# .NET regex's not working - 1# check beginning of text entered #2 check structure

Tags: .net, regex

OK it has unfortunately been a while since I've used REGEX and I am struggling to wonder why its not working with my project.

I have used Regex Tester which says my two tests are valid but when it comes to testing in my project they get rejected.

1) Check the text starts with certain characters

```
[RegularExpression("(spAPP)",ErrorMessage = "Stored procedures must begin with spAPP")]
```

This seems to accept spAPP on it's own, but not something like spAPPabcdef which I want it to. I am struggling to find the "Ignore rest of the text" attribute with REGEX.

2) A bit more complicated. I have certain naming conventions for AD groups, so an example would be "UK ROLE IT APPLICATION DEV ADMIN", up to the role name there are standards (so I need the "UK ROLE IT APPLICATION DEV" checked.

```
[RegularExpression(@"((UK|FRANCE|GERMANY|USA)\s(ROLE)\s(IT|NON-IT)\s(APPLICATION)\s(DEV|TEST|LIVE))", ErrorMessage = "Please use AD naming standards.")]
```

I think it might be the fact I am using () around all the words, but its easier to read in my code. The RegexTester I found seems to indicate that it's right, but again, in my .NET project, it rejects it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

1. `^spAPP.*$`
2. `^((UK|FRANCE|GERMANY|USA)\s(ROLE)\s(IT|NON-IT)\s(APPLICATION)\s(DEV|TEST|LIVE)).*$`

JavaScript implementation behind `RegularExpressionAttribute` needs `^`-string begginning and `$`-string end to be specified.

See: http://blog.regexhero.net/2012/09/aspnet-mvc-dataannotations-and.html

Comment: Thanks #1 works. 2# doesn't though. Thanks for the link as well, I'll read through it.

Comment: @Olly that's strange, are you sure everything is set up right for that property/input? Try with simple regex like `^abc.*$`

Comment: The abc does work. However `^(abc)\s(def).*$` doesn't work when I enter 'abc defsdsdfdfsdf' or 'abc def' so it could be my \s's (thanks BTW)

Comment: I don't think `\s` has anything to do . It may be multiple `(capture groups)` most likely. Check `^(abc)\sdef.*$`

Comment: Hi Anri. No that did not work. `^((abc)(def)).*$` works when I enter 'abcdefdsadsad' and 'abcdef' though.

Comment: @Olly that's creepy, 
you made me want to test it later :)

Comment: Ha I will keep trying as well. Hopefully I'll solve it at some point! Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Olly - I'm not sure if this is the issue.  But the important things (as I explain in the article Anri linked to) are that you use `^` and `$`, and that your regular expression returns *only* one match.

Comment: OK I believe I know why. It's nothing to do with the Regex but infact Kendo UI thats causing the problem. [link](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/general-discussions/regular-expression-validator-not-working-in-grid-popup.aspx)